# ColdFusion UTC TIME LTE Checks vs NonUTC Time

Tags: datetime, coldfusion, cfml, coldfusion-2016

I'm lost I can do a check of Non UTC Times and things work.
But when converting to UTC Times the CFIF doesn't work

NON UTC {ts '2019-11-10 14:59:46'} LTE {ts '2019-11-10 14:00:00'}

UTC if {ts '2019-11-10 21:59:46'} LTE {ts '2019-11-10 21:00:00'}

I'm lost... Can't seem to figure it out.

```
<cfset timenow = #Now()#>

<cfset utimenow = dateConvert("Local2UTC", timenow)>

<cfset admintime = #DateAdd("h", -1, chk.stime)#>
<cfset uadmintime = #DateAdd("h", -1, chk.utcact)#>
```

The chk.stime and chk.utc times are correct. basically it is taking an hr off time for the cancel window.

These are the time stamps created.

```
NON UTC {ts '2019-11-10 14:59:46'} LTE {ts '2019-11-10 14:00:00'}
```

The NonUTC Stamps are time stamps without the UTC Conversions.

```
UTC if {ts '2019-11-10 21:59:46'} LTE {ts '2019-11-10 21:00:00'}
```

NonUTC Stamps

```
<cfif timenow LTE admintime>
This one works fine...
 NON UTC {ts '2019-11-10 14:59:46'} LTE {ts '2019-11-10 14:00:00'}
 Then allow cancel
<cfelse>
This cfelse is activated properly and Can't Cancel.
 Can't Cancel
</cfif>

UTC Stamps
<cfif utimenow LTE uadmintime>
This one does not work
 UTC if {ts '2019-11-10 21:59:46'} LTE {ts '2019-11-10 21:00:00'}
 Then allow cancel
 This UTC Time does not activate properly and allows the cancel.
 Executes/Activates inside the cfif - it should not
 <cfelse>
 Can't Cancel
</cfif>
```

I have also tried to convert to be sure of ODBCTime

```
<cfset uadmintime = createODBCDateTime(uadmintime)>
```

I ended up having to recreate the times, and compare that format.
It now works with both the `<cfif timenow LTE admintime>` and the `DateCompare` as below. This must have been a formatting issue of not liking the `{ts '2019-11-10 14:59:46'} LTE {ts '2019-11-10 14:00:00'}` formatting.

```
<cfset nctime = '#dateformat(uadmintime, "dd-MM-yyyy")# #timeformat(uadmintime, "hh:mm:ss")#'>
<cfset nutctime = '#dateformat(utimenow, "dd-MM-yyyy")# #timeformat(utimenow, "hh:mm:ss")#'>
```

Comment: Your question is unclear.  You refer to variables without stating their values.  You also show some if/else code but don't say whether the if block executes, or the else.

Comment: Edited a bit more.  The NonUTC time executes properly, the UTC Time Does Not

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ColdFusion is a loosely typed language and can keep date/time values in various data types. Standard comparisons like `eq`, `lte`, etc compare variables of different types based on unknown and changing rules so can have unexpected results if CF decides to convert to a different datatype. There are times where you would expect a variable to be a date/time object when really it is a string that passes validates for a date. Different versions of CF, Lucee, etc could act differently or depend on the actual values involved as well.

I recommend **always** using `dateCompare()` when comparing dates...

https://cfdocs.org/datecompare

```
<cfif utimenow LTE uadmintime>
    ...
</cfif>
```

becomes

```
<cfif dateCompare(utimenow, uadmintime) lte 0>
    ...
</cfif>
```

Example code:

https://cffiddle.org/app/file?filepath=e3d24147-8a25-44ff-a98d-5b1e686cd619/d6115113-eead-4214-bc94-13eb7f0456f5/efad9206-b082-4940-bf5d-f4c5001ae2ec.cfm

Comment: Did not work: NEW TRY : DATECOMPARE: {ts '2019-11-11 13:55:29'} vs {ts '2019-11-11 13:30:00'} : Executes the cfif, when it should be the cfelse

Comment: @Merle_the_Pearl you must have the date/times in the correct order for the comparison to work and must check the result. Dates you just listed would correctly result in the first number being larger so value of `1` is output from dateCompare(). **(edited typo in comment)**

Comment: Something isn't right : If I change to <cfif dateCompare(utimenow, uadmintime) eq 1>  {ts '2019-11-11 14:12:24'} LTE {ts '2019-11-11 14:30:00'} does not execute properly, but {ts '2019-11-11 14:14:41'} LTE {ts '2019-11-11 13:30:00'}  does.

Comment: @Merle_the_Pearl You need to look at this more closely. The equivalent to LTE is a result of `-1` from `dateCompare()`. Edit: actually LTE would be `dateCompare(...) LTE 0` to be more precise.

Comment: In other words.... change all of your `date1 LTE date2` to be `dateCompare(date1, date2) LTE 0`.

Comment: Still Not Executing Properly: Using <cfif dateCompare(utimenow, uadmintime) lte 0> DATECOMPARE: {ts '2019-11-11 15:02:25'} LTE {ts '2019-11-11 14:30:00'}?? still does not execute properly

Comment: @Merle_the_Pearl what is your expected outcome of the code in your last comment?

Comment: https://cffiddle.org/app/file?filepath=e3d24147-8a25-44ff-a98d-5b1e686cd619/d6115113-eead-4214-bc94-13eb7f0456f5/efad9206-b082-4940-bf5d-f4c5001ae2ec.cfm

Comment: I think this is a formatting of the time issue and it doesn't like comparing the {ts '2019 etc} - so I need to format the time into something workable I think.

Comment: Was formatting of how the time comparison was happening : <cfset nctime = '#dateformat(canceltime, "dd-MM-yyyy")# #timeformat(canceltime, "hh:mm:ss")#'> worked.